# bash script that checks if file exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

So I have script xxxx.sh  and I have additional options on that script. The question is when user runs this script I need check if the file exist or does not exist? example: `./xxxx.sh -f /examplefolder/anyfilename.Json` 
for that i have this but idk if this will work?

```
# Validations # Does the file exist
if [[ ! -f $JSON_FILE ]]; then
echo "Error: The file $JSON_FILE does not exist."
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Did you try it? Do you have reason to believe it is *not* working?

Comment: It's not clear what the specific technical problem that led you to ask a question is. You're showing code, but not providing enough details to let someone reproduce a problem with that code in a way that's unambiguously the same problem you need our help with. If you don't know if you have a problem or not, it's too early to ask a question here; a Stack Overflow question needs to be about a narrow, specific technical problem _that you actually face_.

Comment: Well when i'm running command    ./xxxx.sh -f    /folder/folder/file.json It still states the file does not exist where in fact it does. Im i running the program wrong?

Comment: @chepner  I tried it

Comment: What's the `-f` option in your script, where is it parsed? Where do you assign a value to the variable `JSON_FILE`? Is your working directory correct or are you using absolute paths?

Comment: @knittl  i got project where user have to take json file and check if it exist . Because tool will work on everyones devices do i have specify a folder or Cant the user specify the folder? for instance (inside the script its that code above)  ./xxx.sh  -f /folder/myjsonfile.json

Comment: @Amateur_ik unfortunately, that didn't answer any of my questions. Where is `JSON_FILE` defined/assigned? How do you parse your command line? Note that you can run your script with `-x` to show exactly how each statement is executed: `sh -x xxx.sh -f /folder/myjsonfile.json` – hopefully this should give you an indication where (and why) your script is not working

Comment: @knittl so if i set the JSON_FILE = $3(positional parameter). Would that work? and how do i structure script better?

Comment: Your question is missing so much information. What will `echo "File=$JSON_FILE" show? Are you sure about the uppercase in `anyfilename.Json`? Does the filename have spaces?